# Como aplicar código CSS salvo dentro de um array usando AngularJS?

Tags: css, html5, angularjs

Estou fazendo um jogo em Web com diferentes níveis e preciso  alterar o estilo de uma div utilizando um código salvo dentro de um array no AngularJS. Além disso, o jogo possui uma divisão na tela, onde em uma metade o usuário digita o código e na outra, aparece o resultado. Cada nível possui um estilo diferente para o background da visualização, então precisa ser carregado toda vez.

A parte do arquivo HTML é a seguinte:

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

E o código referente ao estilo está da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.css = [
    {
        'estilo': 'background-image : url(...); ...'
    }
];
```

Outra forma já testada:

```
$scope.css = [
    {
        //nível 1
        'background-image': 'url(...)',
        'position' : 'absolute',
         ...
    },
    {
        //nível 2
        ...
    }
];
```

Entretanto não estou conseguindo exibir o resultado na visualização. Nada aparece. Tentei adicionar `ng-style="{{css}}"` à div mas não funcionou. Qual a forma correta de fazer essa atribuição de estilo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seria mais fácil você criar o estilo que deseja dentro do arquivo `.css`.

E para validar no `HTML` existe a diretiva no angularJs chamada `ng-class` onde você pode atribuir um estilo com devida condição... Exemplo:

#### No seu arquivo CSS

```
.classe1 {
   background-color: red;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.classe2 {
   background-color: green;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### no seu HTML validaria a div assim:

```
<div ng-class="condição ? 'classe1' : 'classe2"></div>
```

Eu usei um `if` ternario onde sua estrutura é :

```
Condiçao ? se true executa aqui : se false executa aqui ;
```

exemplo:

```
 1 == 1 ? console.log('verdade') : console.log('false');
```

no caso do seu `HTML`se sua condição for verdadeira ira atribuir o classe1 para a `div` senão sera atribuído a classe2

Comment: Meu era apenas o local onde inseria o `ng-controller`. Está funcionando perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda. De qualquer forma, consegui fazer da seguinte maneira: `ng-class="{'level-one': cur_level == '1', 'level-two': cur_level == '2', 'level-three': cur_level == '3'}`